# Driver for LAN to USB

Tags: networking, usb, drivers, lan

My on-board LAN dropped the link frequently, so I got a new PCI-LAN card. Unfortunately, it also drops the link. I had a hardware specialist check my motherboard.  He says some internal links between the northbridge and RJ45 female connector are broken.  So I bought an external USB to LAN device.  It did not come with a driver and I am unable to find one.  It is a Chinese device, and I don't know who manufactured it.  It's Hardware ID is **USB\VID_1A86&PID_E092&REV_0100**.  How do I find a driver?

Comment: Broken traces between the chipset and onboard Ethernet jack wouldn't prevent a PCI Ethernet card from working, so I doubt that's the problem.  Have you tried a different cable or a different port on your switch?

Comment: but  i tried it .that's why i purchase usb to lan device

Comment: yes i tried a different cable and port

Comment: I can't read Chinese, but this looks like it might be a matching driver. Caution: looks like a third party driver site. http://www.itiankong.net/thread-335704-1-1.html

Comment: What operating system are you using?  If it is a non-ancient version of Windows, you generally won't need a special driver for a common device like this.  If you do need a driver, it will be OS-specific, and you will need to match 32 vs. 64 bits of the OS.

Comment: windows 7 and xp service pack 2

Comment: yes model no. writen on it is CH9200

Comment: Seyren that's the driver i want but the site Says Site registration is currently closed, the last open enrollment time: 2015.05.10 (Mother's Day) 9:00 ~ 21:00 by asking for joining

Answer (score 0):

As fixer1234 says, if you are using Windows 7/8, the driver is generic and should install itself from Windows Update.

To test this, you can plug the device into a USB port that you haven't had it in before, you should see the installing device driver window appear in your taskbar.

I've used several of these of different types both manufacturer supplied (e.g. Lenovo) and no-name devices from Amazon. USB "Docking Stations" often also have a similar device built in and I use 3 or 4 different types of those in different locations.